# how to set a limit number of thread in cvxpy

Tags: cvxpy

I'm using CVXPY on a shared computer, and I have to set a limited number of thread.

```
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve(solver=cvx.CVXOPT)
```

is there any option to limit the number of threads for CVXPY solver?

thanks!

Comment: It might be a bit heavy handed but you could use Docker and constrain it to only use a single thread core.

Answer (score 0):

update a solution to the problem. both the CVXPY and NUMPY might create threads according to available cores by default. it's optional to limit OMP_NUM_THREADS before import NUMPY and CVXPY.

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```